# How do I import/add terms to content without removing the existing ones?

Tags: feeds

currently when importing term with feeds all the existing term of of a content are removed and then the terms are imported.

Is there a way to add terms during an import and keep the existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

In processor settings, make sure you select "Update existing content items" and not "Replace ..."

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, it does'nt work.